# Gnu make: "mv: cannot stat ‘./*.{svg,tpl}’: No such file or directory"?

Tags: regex, makefile, gnu-make

I have *.svg and & *.tpl files in my curent directory i wish to move via makefile.

I have a `d3.makefile` such as :

```
done2:
    mkdir -p ../output/India
    mv ./*.{svg,tpl} -t ../output/India
```

When I run it, I get the error message :

[image]

When I run in the shell by hand the following, it works, my files are moved :

```
mv ./*.{svg,tpl} -t ../output/India
```

**Where is my mistake ?**

Comment: At a guess, it sounds as if your makefile uses a shell that does not support the use of curly braces with `mv`. I suggest you verify the shell that you are using, and the shell that Make is using (you can put `$(info $(SHELL))` in your makefile), and if they differ, try choosing the shell you use (by means of `SHELL := ...` in the makefile).

Answer (score 1):

`make` is using a Bourne shell, which doesn't understand braces in glob patterns, rather than `bash`. Just split it into two arguments.

```
done2:
    mkdir -p ../output/India
    mv *.svg *.tpl -t ../output/India
```

Answer (score 0):

find . -regex ".*.(svg\|tpl)" |  xargs mv -t ../output/India